# css3 transform scale chops off top third of image

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand why, when I use scale, it chops off the top third of the photo, if centered, or if left justified, the top and left edges. I gather it has something to do with the scaling occurring from the mid-point of the img. The code I am using seems trivial having no other content other than the button. What causes this and how does one do it correctly so the entire photo displays within the div?

The intended result is that when you press the "+" button, the scaled photo would remain in the original sized div allowing the user to scroll through enlarged photo.

```
<head>
<title>Zoom photo</title>
<style>
.largeimage img { transform:scale(2); }
</style>
<script>
function explody() {
    document.getElementById("photocontainer").classList.add('largeimage');
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div style="overflow:auto;transform-origin: top left;text-align:center;" id="photocontainer" >
<img src="Desktop/graphic/Oliver1950/IMG_0435.jpg">
</div>
<input type="button" onClick="explody();" value="+">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the origin of the scale happens from the center (horizontal and vertical center) of the image. If it is located in a `<div>` close to the top of the page, it will be cut off. If it is located in a `<div>` that is set to hide overflow, it will also be cut off.

The trick is to either make space around the wrapping `<div>` to accommodate expanded dimensions of the image, or simply alter the `transform-origin` property.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: top center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but by removing img from the class (which I think emulates what made yours work since you apply universally to div), the entire photo displays. But then I'm scaling the entire div which expands the page rather than keeping the photo in the area of the original load and adding scroll bars. I realize now I should have mentioned that. With the img on the class, it works as expected only missing the top portion of the photo, the remainder is within the scrolling div. Am I abusing the div to get that effect?

Comment: I spoke too soon and didn't change the comment fast enough. Removal of the img from the class was the start of the solution. To meet the entire use case, I also had to wrap the existing div in another with style="overflow:auto", this caused the photo to fully display, and do so within the original size of the unscaled photo. Perfect, and thanks for helping see this.